# Least count of Vernier

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

Is least count not always 1 main scale divsion-1vernier scale divsion or is it always least reading possible on main scale/ no of vernier divsions.
question:
1 main scale reading be 1 mm
Lets say 5 main scale reading coincide with 8 vernier scale division then what is least count?
1-5/8= 3/8 mm or 1/8 mm.

if for above vernier scale, the Main scale reading is 35, and 4th divison of vernier coincides with main scale. (zero error=0).
then why is this wrong:
Main scale reading + Least count* Vernier scale reading
35+ 3/8 *4 =36.5

Answer (score 2):

You have not designed a "conventional" vernier scale.

Let the distance between two consecutive main scale divisions (pitch) be $D$ and the distance between two vernier scale divisions be $V$.

The connection between $D$ and $V$ is $(n-1)D = nV$ with $\frac Dn$ and $D-V$ being called the least count.

So you can have $5\, (=n-1)$ main scale divisions equal to $6\, (=n)$ vernier divisions but "you need to work harder" if you have $5\, (=n-3)$ main scale divisions equal to $8\, (=n)$ vernier divisions.

Here is a picture of your main scale $D$ and vernier scale $V3$ with $5$ main scale divisions equal to 8 vernier scale divisions.

[image]

The vernier scale $V3$ is moved to the position where the $1$ on the vernier scale first coincides with a main scale graduation $(36).

[image]

The vernier has moved $\frac 38$ of a main scale division and so the reading is $35 \frac 38$ with the least count being $\frac 3 8$.

Now keep moving the vernier passing coincidence between a main scale mark and $2$ and $3$ on the vernier scale until coincidence with $4$ on the vernier scale is reached.

[image]

The vernier has moved along $4 \times \frac 3 8 = 1\frac 12$ and the reading is $35 + 1\frac 12 = 36.5$

Now the vernier scale can be relabeled as shown for $V1$ in red.
Starting at a reading of $35$ move the vernier scale until the first coincidence of any vernier scale division with the main scale.

[image]

The vernier has moved $\frac 18$ and the reading is $35\frac 18$ with the least count being $\frac 18$.

Keep moving the vernier scale passing coincidence with red $2$ and red $3$ to have coincidence between the main scale and red $4$ which happens to be the same label as that on vernier scale $V3$.

[image]

The vernier scale has now moved $4 \times \frac 18 = \frac 12$ and the reading is $35\frac 12$.

---

Note that the scale reading on $V1$ is equal to modulo $8$ of three times a scale reading on $V3$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula LC=MSD-VSD is only valid for vernier calipers having n VSD = n-1 MSD.

The second formula LC=MSD/n I do not have a clue about but it might be that if n VSD =m MSD and m and n are coprime then LC=MSD/n . No idea how to actually prove it, but some linear combination might be necessary.

Comment: Could you provide more information about your problem? Maybe describe the problem, spell out the acronyms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For a non standard vernier calipers, if m divisions on the main scale are equal to n divisions on the vernier scale i.e.
$mMSD=nVSD$ the least count will be $\frac{MSD}{n}$,where m and n are relatively prime.

Proof: firstly, least count can be understood as the least distance that the vernier scale has to slide from the zero mark for a Main scale divison to coincide with a vernier scale division.so let the $p^{th}$ divison on the main scale  and the $q^{th}$ divison on the vernier scale be closest to each other,the distance between these two will represent the least count
$$LC=p.MSD-q.VSD =\frac{MSD}{n}(pn-qm)$$
Now we need to prove that we can always find p and q such that $pn-qm=1$ or $n=\frac{qm+1}{p}=$ some integer. Now since p and q are relatively prime we can always find m such that $qm\equiv-1(modp)$

therefore the reading will be main scale reading$+4($least count$)=35+4(0.125)=35.5$